# How can I easily find Masks of Yalung?

Tags: far-cry-4

Sometimes I mark such a Mask on the map and run or fly to this point. But I can't find the Mask at this point.

Do you know a better way to detect it? Something like a 'Make Yalung visible injection'?

I hate it do use pages like this http://segmentnext.com/2014/11/18/far-cry-4-masks-yalung-locations-guide/

Do you know any handy tips how I can find them by myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already stated, **buy the maps**, once you have the maps you can set a waypoint that will disappear when you are close to the mask however it usually is close enough to give you an idea of the level the mask is located.

Secondly **look for a dead body and a note**, the mask is left by a serial killer at the scene of the crime, this will let you know that you are definitely in the right location and the mask should be nearby.

Finally **listen for the audio cue**, as you wander around in the blue circle you should hear a low note repeated that will start quietly and increase in volume as you get closer to the mask.

Also worth noting is that the mask isn't always out in the open, **look around** under tables, in boxes or underwater. It can also be in an inaccessible location, in this case you can **shoot it**.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you didn't do that already, buy all the maps. Then all those Masks of Yalung will appear on your map.

Then set a waypoint to the Mask symbol. You know can tell whether the Mask is in the mountains or on ground level. 
But as soon as you get close to it (>50M I think) the waypoint will disappear.

I don't know a better way to collect them - it helped me getting all the collectibles in FC3 and FC4.

Comment: Thanks! This is how I do it actually. But HOW can I tell if the Mask is in the mountains, on the ground or even in a cave inside the hill?

Comment: @PeterCo I haven't found a better method yet, but I didn't have trouble reading the map with the additional help of the waypoints. My strategy is to go up as high as possible around the waypoint and then make my way down to it. It usually worked pretty well. Southern Kyrat has, I think two or three tough ones (the ones along the mountains bordering the north in south western Kyrat), where you really have to walk for a few minutes and figure out a way to get to the location.

Comment: @PeterCo Look at the waypoint marker in your FOV to see if it's above or below you. Once it's on your level but buried in rock, you'll need to find a cave. There have been a few that were sitting in the open, and I missed them simply because I expected them all to be hidden. There are also a few that you must destroy because they are too high or behind bars in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

With the appropriate skill, when you reach an area with the mask in, use your camera. Spin 360 slowly and you'll see the mask will appear as a yellow mark in your view. You can then waypoint it (when underwater) though your camera as said in the skill description or you can just walk toward it with the camera still out.